# Does VS Online support building ASP.NET 5?

Tags: azure-devops, asp.net-core

I set up a build definition in VS Online for an ASP.NET 5 project and tried to get it automatically built and deployed to an Azure Website.

But I'm seeing a build failure thrown by MSBuild as below.

`C:\a\src\src\WebApp1\WebApp1.kproj(7,3): error MSB4019: The imported project "C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v12.0\AspNet\Microsoft.Web.AspNet.Props" was not found. Confirm that the path in the <Import> declaration is correct, and that the file exists on disk.`

Looks like VS Online is not supporting ASP.NET 5. Am I right? If that's the case, when can I expect that to happen? Do I have to wait until ASP.NET 5 is officially release?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We haven't added it to the build machines yet. We are planning to do so in about a month.

Comment: Hi. It has been more than a month and ASP.NET 5 and DNX is still breaking my builds in VSO.   Any ideas? Workarounds? I tried uploading files manually to source control and modifying my project files. But it seems to be pulling a lot more stuff from my user folder in windows....

Comment: Still appears to be an issue.  Are we any closer?

Answer (score 3):

Although they have not added it to the provided hosted build service you can still build ASP.NET 5 from VSO.

If you spin up a VM on Azure using your complementary MSDN credits you can install your own build agent and pit VS 2015 on there. That will give you the capability to compile with whatever technologies you like.

Once VSO rolls out production support you can just bin that VM.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. That's a good approach. I managed to set up a build controller and agent in a Azure hosted VM where VS 2015 CTP 6 has been installed, also linked to VSO. But unfortunately I'm seeing another issue: 

`C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v14.0\AspNet\Microsoft.Web.AspNet.targets (111): The ProjectK Runtime package needs to be installed. See output window for more details.`

Actually K runtime has already been installed. Do I need to pass extra MSBUILD command parameters for my own build service to work with ASP.NET 5 projects?

Answer (score 1):

It's possible to use a Hosted agent, but you have to jump through some hoops. This article explains what powershell scripts you need to add and how to configure your build.

[Build and Deploy your ASP.NET 5 Application to an Azure Web App](https://msdn.microsoft.com/Library/vs/alm/Build/azure/deploy-aspnet5)